# Missing Code Analysis output file breaking TFS builds

Tags: tfs

We have an occasional issue whereby the build cannot find a Code Analysis output file and fails the build with this message:

[image]

Much of the help surrounding this message deals with path name length which I'm pretty sure doesn't apply here as when the build is re-queued, it goes thru fine. There is also no Code Analysis related cruft in the project files to get rid of - just the standard:

```
<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
```

We also don't simply want to turn Code Analysis off for the builds as that would rather defeat the object.

Has anyone else encountered this? Also, any idea how we might get round it?

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: The solutions are all for VS2013 I believe...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS2010 or earlier, it turns out that some code analysis tags in the .csproj file were causing the issue. Please see this post [Hot to get rid of code analysis errors in TFS build](http://aforcina.blogspot.jp/2013/04/hot-to-get-rid-of-code-analysis-errors.html) for details.

If not, try to clean the Team Build workspace.